# How can I set pixels in Java BufferedImages using non-ARGB color spaces?

Tags: java, bufferedimage, color-space

I'm writing an application that needs to work with 16-bit "5-5-5" RGB colors (that is, 5 bits for each color and one bit of padding).  In order to handle these images, I am using the [BufferedImage](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/image/BufferedImage.html) class provided by AWT.  The BufferedImage class specifically allows for the usage of non-RGB color spaces by taking either a ColorModel object or a predefined image type constant - one of which is the 5-5-5 pixel format that I need.

My problem is this: the BufferedImage "setRGB()" method states in its description that color values provided are "assumed to be in the default RGB color model, TYPE_INT_ARGB, and default sRGB color space" (per the BufferedImage documentation page).  No other method seems to accept values designed for different color spaces, either.

**Is there a way to use my non-standard color space directly with BufferedImage, or would I have to rely on the class's internal color conversion mechanisms to handle all of my colors?** (Or am I just misreading/misunderstanding something about how the class works?)

Comment: You may need to make use of the `Raster`, for example [`BufferedImage#setData`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/awt/image/BufferedImage.html#setData(java.awt.image.Raster)) - there are a number of other supporting methods for the raster you can look at as well

Comment: Call [`getRaster()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/image/BufferedImage.html#getRaster--), then use its methods to work with pixels.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`BufferedImage.TYPE_USHORT_555_RGB` still uses a completely standard RGB color space (in fact, it uses `sRGB`), so I don't think a different *color space* is what you are looking for.

If you want to perform painting or other operations in Java, just use the normal methods like `setRGB/getRGB()` and `createGraphics()/Grapics2D`. Everything will be properly converted to and from the packed `USHORT_555_RGB` format for you.

For example:

```
BufferedImage image = new BufferedImage(w, h, BufferedImage.TYPE_USHORT_555_RGB);

// Do some custom painting
Graphics2D g = image.createGraphics();
g.drawImage(otherImage, 0, 0, null); // image type here does not matter
g.setColor(Color.ORANGE);            // Color in sRGB, but does not matter
g.fillOval(0, 0, w, h);
g.dispose();

image.setRGB(0, h/2, w, 1, new int[w]); // Silly way to create a horizontal black line at the center of the image... Don't do this, use fillRect(0, h/2, 1, w)! ;-)  

// image will still be USHORT_555_RGB *internally*
```

---

However, if you have pixel data in the `USHORT_555_RGB` format (ie. from an external library/api/service), it may be faster and more accurate to set these values directly to the raster/databuffer. Or if you need to pass the pixel values back to the same library/api/service.

For example, using the `Raster`:

```
BufferedImage image = new BufferedImage(w, h, BufferedImage.TYPE_USHORT_555_RGB);

// Some fictional API. It's assumed that data.length == w * h
short[] apiPixels = api.getPixelsUSHORT_555_RGB(w, h);

WritableRaster raster = image.getRaster();

// Set short values to image
raster.setDataElements(0, 0, w, h, apiPixels);
        
// Get short values from image
short[] pixels = (short[]) raster.getDataElements(0, 0, w, h, null); // TYPE_USHORT_555_RGB -> always short[]
api.setPixels(pixels, w, h); // Another fictional API
```

Or, alternatively, use the `DataBuffer`:

```
BufferedImage image = new BufferedImage(w, h, BufferedImage.TYPE_USHORT_555_RGB);

// Some fictional API. It's assumed that data.length == w * h
short[] apiPixels = api.getPixelsUSHORT_555_RGB(w, h);

DataBufferUShort buffer = (DataBufferUShort) image.getRaster().getDataBuffer(); // TYPE_USHORT_555_RGB -> always DataBufferUShort

// Set short values to image
System.arraycopy(apiPixels, 0, buffer.getData(), 0, apiPixels.length);

// Get short values from image
api.setPixels(buffer.getData(), w, h);
```

In most cases it does not matter which method you use, but the first approach (using `Raster` only) may keep the image managed, which will make images *display* faster on screen from your Java process.

---

PS: If a different color space is *really* what you need (ie. the pixel array from the external library/api/service uses a different color space, and you need to view the pixels in this color space), you can create a `BufferedImage` in `USHORT_555_RGB` style with a custom color space like this:

```
// Either use one of the built-in color spaces, or load one from disk
ColorSpace colorSpace = ColorSpace.getInstance(ColorSpace.CS_LINEAR_RGB);
ColorSpace colorSpaceToo = new ICC_ColorSpace(ICC_Profile.getInstance(Files.newInputStream(new File("/path/to/custom_rgb_profile.icc").toPath())));

// Create a color model using your color space, TYPE_USHORT and 5/5/5 mask, no transparency
ColorModel colorModel = new DirectColorModel(colorSpace, 15, 0x7C00, 0x03E0, 0x001F, 0, false, DataBuffer.TYPE_USHORT);

// And finally, create an image from the color model and a compatible raster
BufferedImage imageToo = new BufferedImage(colorModel, colorModel.createCompatibleWritableRaster(w, h), colorModel.isAlphaPremultiplied(), null);
```

Just remember that as the Java2D graphics operations and `setRGB/getRGB` are still using sRGB, now all operations on your image will be converted back and forth between your color space and sRGB. Performance will not be as good.

Comment: Through working further on my project, I've realized that there's a way to sidestep this issue entirely; however, this information is very useful for other parts of my project.  I am working with reading and writing image files that use ushort555 color; while I don't need perfect accuracy when viewing them within my program, I will need to read this kind of data from a file. The raster solution you've provided will work perfectly fine for my purposes.